# Count values in CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv

The .csv file:

```
question1,question2,question3,question4,question5,question6,question7,question8,question9,question10
yes,response,response,response,response,response,response,response,response,response
yes,response2,response2,response2,response2,response2,response2,response2,response2,response2
no,response3,response3,response3,response3,response3,response3,response3,response3,response3
```

I want to get this result in php.

$question = "the_question_goes_here"

question1
yes = 2
no = 1

The code must find the unique responses for each question and count how many of each.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have any control over how the CSV file gets generated?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Can you do my homework for me?

Answer (score 0):

`str_getcsv()` can be used to get a csv string as an array.

Using this you can write a loop over the array which counts up values (in pseudocode):

```
counts = array;
//Loop over each row
for(row in csvrows){
     for(cell in row){
         counts[rowHeader][cellValue] = counts[rowHeader][cellValue]+1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick reading the file contents into PHP

```
$data= array();    
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        foreach ($data as $position => $value)  {
            if($row == 1) {
                $data[$position]['question'] = $value;
                $data[$position]['yes'] = 0;
                $data[$position]['no'] = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if ($value == 'yes') {
                  $data[$position]['yes'] = $data[$position]['yes'] + 1
            } elseif ($value == 'no') {
                  $data[$position]['no'] = $data[$position]['no'] + 1
            }
        }
        $row++;            
    }        
    fclose($handle);
}
```

This will return a array which you can read like this

- Array value

  - 'question' key holding text
  - 'yes' key holding numOf yes
  - 'no'key holding numOf no

Comment: Couldn't get this one to work. It's also important that the code finds all the unique responses by itself.

Comment: This should get you started though. I'm not going to write the entire solution. Try building upon this one or any other answers in here. Report back with a different in depth question if you can't work it out.